# Discord Bot: How would I make this work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I currently have a python discord bot script that grabs an API of a price of a certain coin, however, whenever I try to put it into the 'client.change_presence' it gives me a "must be a str, not a list" error.

I tried to convert it into a string, as you will see in my source code, but this did not work either, coming up with: "TypeError: Can Only Join An Iterable"

```
import requests
import discord
import asyncio

url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()['BTC_PLSR']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    list = data['last']
    price = print('PLSR Price:', data['last'])
    string = ''.join(list)

    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="PLSR Price: " + string))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        counter = 0
        tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Calculating messages...')
        async for log in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=100):
            if log.author == message.author:
                counter += 1

        await client.edit_message(tmp, 'You have {} messages.'.format(counter))
    elif message.content.startswith('!sleep'):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Done sleeping')





client.run('Removed Token for Security Reasons')
```

How can I make this work? Thanks! (Python 3.6.4)

Comment: Post your code here, in your question, with proper format, so people can see without going to a third party site, and still be able to copy and paste

Comment: What is the `PSLR` line printing?

Comment: Everything like, works, I just want it to set the Discord Status to: PLSR Price: + the price from the API.

Comment: You should also know that using `requests` with asynchronous code [can cause problems](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean). You should use `aiohttp` instead to avoid unnecessary blocking.

Comment: name="PLSR Price: {}".format(last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['last']` is a float, not some iterable of strings.  Just use `str(data['last'])`

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    last = str(data['last'])
    price = print('PLSR Price:', last)

    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="PLSR Price: " + last))
```